How to identify which SID is wrong in ORA-12505?
I currently have 3 DataSourceConfig classes annotated with @Configuration that will each build a different connection (there are 3 dbs total).
@Bean("DataSourceA")
public DataSource DataSourceA() {
    log.info("Initializing A");
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .url(url).driverClassName(driverClass)
            .username(username).password(password).build();
}

@Bean("DataSourceB")
public DataSource dataSourceB() {
    log.info("Initializing B");
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .url(url).driverClassName(driverClass)
            .username(username).password(password).build();
}

@Bean("DataSourceC")
public DataSource DataSourceC() {
    log.info("Initializing C");
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .url(url).driverClassName(driverClass)
            .username(username).password(password).build();
}

Now, the issue is that when any one of the SID is wrong, I have no idea which is wrong because the log would be something like:
2024-06-07 14:34:30.025 [main] INFO  com.org.myapp.service.config.DataSourceConfigA - Initializing A
2024-06-07 14:34:30.084 [main] INFO  com.org.myapp.service.config.DataSourceConfigB - Initializing B
2024-06-07 14:34:30.098 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-06-07 14:34:31.177 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
 
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.lambda$logDataSources$1(H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java:86) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:395) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.logDataSources(H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java:92) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.lambda$h2Console$0(H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java:68) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.withThreadContextClassLoader(H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java:77) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.h2Console(H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java:68) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:262) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:236) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5211) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) [?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1383) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) [?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:430) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.70.jar:9.0.70]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) [spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) [spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at com.org.myapp.service.AppService.main(ApertureService.java:24) [classes/:?]
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
 
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:271) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:317) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518) ~[ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    ... 84 more

Now, I could guess that the first pool connection HikariPool-1 would be the DataSource A, but when I have an error in initializing DataSource B, it says that the exception is in HikariPool-3, and these aren't always the same order so the logging isn't really helping. How can I get the HikariCP error logs to be more intuitive i.e. logging out the SID or URL that has an issue?

Increase log level for Hikari with: logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG This will show you all details.

Its giving me a lot more details than I really need, but I guess it is sort of acceptable. Would be great if I can only log out the jdbcUrl from the hikariConfig

You can reduce the logs to config details on startup only with logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG

DataSourceBuilder is the wrong tool in this case as it only provides access to a subset of the configuration options.
When configuring one datasource per application context and making use of many then also make use of the property spring.datasource.hikari.name to configure the pool name (also see org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getName()). You can choose a name that will make it clear which database is affected. When for example choosing name FooDB your above error message would read
ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - FooDB - Exception during pool initialization.

instead.
When configuring more than one datasource per application context better repeat what spring-boot itself is doing with org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.Hikari. I don't know of a good alternative than copy pasting this if you want to stick with one application context.
